Why am I getting an empty stack error on line return Minstack.peek();
class MinStack {
    Stack<Integer> stack;
    Stack<Integer> Minstack;

    public MinStack() {
        stack = new Stack();
        Minstack = new Stack();

    }

    public void push(int val) {
        stack.push(val);

        int min = val;

        if (Minstack.isEmpty()) {
            Minstack.push(min);
        }

        else {
            if (Minstack.peek() > min) {
                Minstack.push(min);
            }
        }
    }

    public void pop() {
        int val = stack.pop();

        if (Minstack.peek() == val) {
            Minstack.pop();
        }
    }

    public int top() {
        return stack.peek();
    }

    public int getMin() {
        return Minstack.peek(); <----------------------------------- HERE
    }
}

/**
 * Your MinStack object will be instantiated and called as such:
 * MinStack obj = new MinStack();
 * obj.push(val);
 * obj.pop();
 * int param_3 = obj.top();
 * int param_4 = obj.getMin();
 */

I've tried my own code with two stacks (stack and minstack) where I push only the current minimum values
but here in the given test case I'm wondering why the stack is empty? because I've made sure to push the minimun value from the start
here's the test case


Apparently you do not always push the minimum.

The idea is to always maintain two "parallel" stacks - every time you push an element to the stack, you must push the current minimum, and when you pop the stack, you of course pop the minimum too. This way, you can always maintain the up-to-date minimum.
In your code, you conditionally push and pop into the minstack, meaning that the two stacks will get out of sync. Instead of checking whether or not you should pop or push to the stack, you should be checking what value you are pushing or popping:
 public void push(int val) {
    stack.push(val);

    // Check if val is the new minimum
    // If it is - push it.
    // If it isn't, re-push the current mimum
    int min = val;
    if (!minstack.isEmpty() && minstack.peek() < min) {
        min = minstack.peek();
    }
    minstack.push(min);
}

public void pop() {
    // Pop both stacks
    stack.pop();
    minstack.pop();
}


The testCase attempts to push the following : 0, 1, 0.
You only push a new value on the stack, if the current value at the top of the stack is > the value you are trying to push.
So your min stack will take 0, skip 1 and again skip 0.
After 3 pushes:
stack = [0, 1, 0],
minStack = [0]
getMin = minStack.peek = 0
Then you do a pop.
So stack = [0, 1],
minStack = []
Now getMin = minStack.peek() = not possible because stack is empty.
Your code doesn't account for what happens when there are multiple instances of the same min.
